# JavaScript Using FileReader with server images

Tags: javascript, image, filereader

I know the functioning of javascript FileReader as described here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
which is "user select a file by input module or drag box and javascript processes it.".
I was wondering, though, if I could use use the FileReader functionality by feeding it with urls of files (images in my case) from the server where the site is running.

Does anyone know about this? In case, can you explain to me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

To read an HTTP response (such as a file) from the server, use AJAX (`XMLHttpRequest`)